# CSS adjacent sibling breaks dropdown menu margin

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to implement a CSS dropdown menu, based on this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar) from w3schools. It is working, but the left margin around the `dropbtn` class is not the same as the left margin for the simple navigation links(Home, News). As you move from the one list item to another the item implementing the dropdown menu has a black border on the left that I cannot explain.

This behavior started when I attempted to implement a divider between the items using li+li:before as shown [here](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FBGF7020T28C).

**default.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
    <p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li+li:before {
    color: white;
    content: "|";
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: it seems to be fine for me...where exactly is this black line?

Comment: @SergChernata On hover the background of Home and News list items change from black to red. The background of the Dropdown list items also changes to red, but on the left margin there is a small area, maybe 5px wide that remains black. Having thought it through I'm guessing the | character is wider than it appears, can I fix this with a negative margin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just position that `before` element a little more precisely:

```
li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

li+li:before {
    color: white;
    content: "|";
    left: -1px;
    top: 14px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oao3yt8w/

Comment: Your solution appears to have fixed the margin, but the dropdown is no longer working?

Comment: Updated the fiddle. Had to get rid of overflow:hidden on your ul and add height to it. https://jsfiddle.net/oao3yt8w/1/